# Add a link on the reputation score on meta sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, per-site-meta

Clicking on your reputation score at the top of the screen on longer take you to the privileges page. Instead, it shows you a breakdown of the reputation you've recently gained.

It's quite clearly an attempt at replacing the recent envelope. However, since a site's meta didn't have a link there before, the breakdown is only available by clicking on the profile first.

Could you remedy that? I like to keep track of my reputation of meta site.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation on child metas is horribly tricky business.

The concept I had with the reputation link on the rep number is ... click here to see why that number, is this number:

[image: why]

If I link that to the rep report on meta, it is all **lies**. Even worse, the reputation bar on child meta is not counting the intervals (day, week month) properly cause rep is not tracked.

---

Oddly enough probably the correct thing to do on child metas is remove the reputation row from the user popup... and rename the user reputation tab to "voting" or "votes".

Answer (score 1):

On metas, we now show votes instead of reputation on that first line:

[image]

Comment: Fine, but all what I want is an hyperlink on "votes" and/or the reputation score to [this page](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/45/borror0?tab=reputation) so I can easily see which of my meta posts have been upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over your username and wait for the box to pop up, you'll get a link to your privileges. Isn't that what you want?

**Edit:** Wait, are you asking for the rep breakdown? That's available (at least on M.SO) by clicking on the reputation score, as you said. Is this not the case for other meta sites?

I'm confused.

Comment: The privileges page did not work on per-site-metas of the new sites, so the element never linked.

Comment: @Grace: Ooooooh, okay. It's essentially functionality that's here on M.SO that he wants on the other meta sites?

Comment: Kinda. Essentially, the target of the reputation link is now the reputation breakdown, which is now accessible on the per-site-metas. So since the target is now valid (which privileges were not), the request is to re-enable having the reputation be a link there.

Comment: You can't access the rep breakdown on other metas by clicking the reputation score.